# Input bug: cannot type 'S' into search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I almost give up on this bug.
I simply just can't type "S" into the search input.

The keyboard works fine.

Sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-raman-61zbx?file=/src/App.js

Code from sandbox:

```
import {
  Box,
  FormControl,
  InputAdornment,
  ListItem,
  Menu,
  TextField,
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  clamp,
  difference,
  includes,
  intersection,
  join,
  map,
  union
} from "lodash";

import ArrowDropDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDown";
import { FixedSizeList } from "react-window";
import Fuse from "fuse.js";
import React from "react";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import memoize from "memoize-one";

const styles = {
  popoverPaper: {
    width: "100%"
  }
};

const fuseOptions = {
  includeScore: true
};

const initialSearchState = {
  searchValue: ""
};

const getCheckedList = (list) => (!!list ? list : []);

class VirtualisedSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: null,
      ...initialSearchState
    };
  }

  getSearchList = memoize((list, searchValue) => {
    const fuse = new Fuse(list, fuseOptions);
    return !!searchValue ? map(fuse.search(searchValue), (o) => o.item) : list;
  });

  handleSearch = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      searchValue: event.target.value
    });
  };

  getCleanSelectedValues = memoize((currentSelectedValues, list) =>
    intersection(currentSelectedValues, list)
  );

  getNewMultipleValue = (currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue) =>
    includes(currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue)
      ? difference(currentSelectedValues, [clickedItemValue])
      : union(currentSelectedValues, [clickedItemValue]);

  getNewSingleValue = (currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue) =>
    includes(currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue) ? [] : [clickedItemValue];

  getNewValue = (currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue, list, multiple) =>
    multiple
      ? this.getNewMultipleValue(
          this.getCleanSelectedValues(currentSelectedValues, list),
          clickedItemValue
        )
      : this.getNewSingleValue(currentSelectedValues, clickedItemValue);

  handleChange = (currentSelectedValues, list, multiple) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: null
    });
    const clickedItemValue = event.target.getAttribute("value");
    const newValue = this.getNewValue(
      currentSelectedValues,
      clickedItemValue,
      list,
      multiple
    );
    this.props.onSelect(newValue);
  };

  getTextFieldDisplayValue = (value, list, labelMap) =>
    join(
      map(this.getCleanSelectedValues(value, list), (e) => labelMap[e] ?? e),
      ", "
    );

  handleMenuOpen = (event) => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleMenuClose = (event) => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null, ...initialSearchState });
  };

  renderRow = () => ({ index, style }) => {
    const { multiple, value, list, labelMap } = this.props;
    const { searchValue } = this.state;
    const searchList = this.getSearchList(list, searchValue);

    const cleanSelectedValues = this.getCleanSelectedValues(value, list);
    const listItem = searchList[index];
    return (
      <ListItem
        value={listItem}
        key={listItem}
        selected={includes(value, listItem)}
        onClick={this.handleChange(cleanSelectedValues, list, multiple)}
        style={style}
      >
        {labelMap?.[listItem] || listItem}
      </ListItem>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      value,
      list,
      name,
      label,
      labelMap,
      required = false,
      classes
    } = this.props;
    const { searchValue } = this.state;
    const formControlClassNames = this.props?.classes?.formControl;

    const searchList = this.getSearchList(getCheckedList(list), searchValue);
    const nItems = searchList.length;
    const stringHeight = 46;
    const fixedSizeListHeight = stringHeight * clamp(nItems, 1, 10);

    return (
      <FormControl className={formControlClassNames} fullWidth>
        <TextField
          onClick={this.handleMenuOpen}
          variant="outlined"
          required={required}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <ArrowDropDownIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
          value={this.getTextFieldDisplayValue(value, list, labelMap)}
          multiline
          type="text"
          name={name}
          label={label}
          fullWidth
        />
        <Menu
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(this.state.anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleMenuClose}
          PopoverClasses={{ paper: classes.popoverPaper }}
        >
          {/* Search */}
          <Box p={1}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
              type="text"
              label={"Search"}
              value={searchValue}
              onChange={this.handleSearch}
              fullWidth
            />
          </Box>

          {/* Virtualized list */}
          <FixedSizeList
            height={fixedSizeListHeight}
            width={"100%"}
            itemSize={stringHeight}
            itemCount={nItems}
          >
            {this.renderRow()}
          </FixedSizeList>
        </Menu>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

VirtualisedSelector.defaultProps = {
  value: "",
  list: [],
  name: "",
  label: "",
  labelMap: {},
  required: false
};

export default withStyles(styles)(VirtualisedSelector);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in the question. You can link off-site for supporting resources, but the question should be answerable without leaving.

Comment: I haven't managed to track down the problem, but I discovered that: 1) it works fine without the `<Menu>` component, meaning the problem might be there 2) the behavior is similar to `S` functioning as a hotkey used for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you shouldn't be using `Menu` for this. `Menu` assumes that it has `MenuItem` children and has accessibility functionality geared towards that assumption. The behavior you are seeing is caused by the functionality that tries to navigate to menu items by typing the character that the menu item's text starts with. In your case, it is finding the text of the label "Search", and then it is moving focus to that "menu item" (which is why you then get a focus outline on the div containing your `TextField`). If you change the label to "Type Here", you'll find the "s" works, but "t" doesn't.

My recommendation would be to use [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#popover) directly (the lower-level component which `Menu` delegates to for the main functionality you are using from it). Another option would be to use the [Autocomplete component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) since you seem to be trying to use `Menu` and the pop-up `TextField` to do your own custom version of what the `Autocomplete` component provides.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19116) in MenuList of Material UI. The Menu component [internally uses MenuList](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1406f5137b57a14c2623affd6bac52d08fd17e1b/packages/material-ui/src/Menu/Menu.js#L184), so it also has the issue.

You can work around this behaviour by preventing the [bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) of the event of the TextField (as stated in the Github thread).

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <SearchIcon />
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
  type="text"
  label={"Search"}
  value={searchValue}
  onChange={this.handleSearch}
  onKeyDown={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
  fullWidth
/>
```